# Regex - str_extract_all returns list and not vector

Tags: regex, r

i need to extract the prices from this vector, without the symbol: "S/."

**Eg: "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 499.95"   -> 499.95**

**Or:  "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,099.95" -> 1,099.95**

This is my attemp:

```
precios <- str_extract_all(tvs_prices, "[0-9]*\\,[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$")
```

This is my vector:

```
 [1] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 499.95"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 9,999" "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 899"      "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,349"
 [5] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,499" "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,999" "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 699"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 499"  
 [9] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 899"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 999"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,099"     "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,299"
 [13] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 299"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 699"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,099" "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,899"
 [17] "\r\n\t\t\tS/. 1,499"
```

But i get this results:

a) A list,

b) Some contains "character(0)" within elements of the list.

I don't need a list, but a vector, as a number (as.numeric()):

```
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "9,999"
```

When trying to be more specific, using "^", i just get a list containing: "character(0)":

Code:

```
precios <- str_extract_all(tvs_prices, "^[0-9]*\\,[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$")

For all the elements in the list (i don't need a list but a vector):

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)
```

And so on for all the elements on the original vector...

Comment: don't you need `"[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$"` (? after the comma) ? (it would be easier to test if you used `dput()` to show your sample input)

Comment: If the part wanted always follows the last space, as in examples in  the question, then `sub(".* ", "", tvs_prices)` would do it.

Comment: Thanks to all. @G.Grothendieck It did the trick, may you explain why my code did not work, and/or what does your's exactly? Also, i tried this: tvs_prices3 <- as.numeric(sub(".* ", "", tvs_prices)) ... because i need to apply math operations to it, but got "NA introduced by coercion". Thanks.

Comment: (1) Your pattern demands a comma but not all the strings matched have a comma.  (2) ".* " means match anything (a dot is any character) as many times as possible (*) followed by a space " ".  To convert the result to numreric: `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))` where `x` is the result of the `sub`.

Comment: Ok, i tried this (just to learn):     prices_prices <- sub("^[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$", "", tvs_prices)... but got this:    "[1] "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 499"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 9,999" "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 899"   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\tS/. 1,349"..so on... With out the decimal part... may you tell me why? @G.Grothendieck ---notice the ,? making the comma optional.

Answer (score 0):

This regex extracts a number:

```
\d*(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?
```